# Identityserver 4 User Account Management

Tags: angular, identityserver4

I successfully separated my authentication server from my resource server. Now I have the challenge of managing user accounts. i.e create new account, delete user, update user etc.I am unable to access the AccountController on the AuthServer. I did come across [Identity Manger Tutorial](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity) by Scott Brady, I tried following this tutorial but I run into compatibility issues with the following error:

```
Errors in C:\Users\Julius\Documents\Projects\School\Development\In Progress\1\ReportBook\ReportBook.Auth\ReportBook.Auth.xproj
Package IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity 1.0.0-beta5-1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity 1.0.0-beta5-1 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package IdentityManager 1.0.0-beta5-5 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package IdentityManager 1.0.0-beta5-5 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
Package IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity 1.0.0-beta5-1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) / win10-x64. Package IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity 1.0.0-beta5-1 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package IdentityManager 1.0.0-beta5-5 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) / win10-x64. Package IdentityManager 1.0.0-beta5-5 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) / win10-x64. Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) / win10-x64. Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (win10-x64).
```

I'd love to use and angular 2 as the front end in building a user account management system.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately IdentityManager only works with ASP.NET 4.x . If you're using Core/IdentityServer4 you're going to have to build your own set of CRUD APIs for your identity management system.

Comment: Thanks, I have trying that and some how after authentication and authorization I am unable to send requests to the AuthServer where the controller for managing users. I tried doing this on the resource server but had problems injecting UserManager. I am however able to inject the ApplicationDBContext and can use the context directly here but I cant seem to find a way of creating user account as is done using UserManager. I was of the opinion that once I am able to authenticate and access resources on the resource server I should be able to do same on the Auth Server.